# Multiple material-ui tooltips open on click

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, user-controls, material-ui, tooltip

I'm trying to use 2 Material-UI tooltips in the same parent component. Also, I need a custom control for the open and close action of the tooltips. So, I used the *open* and *setOpen* states using the *UseState* hook.

How can I maintain separate states for the 2 tooltips that I use, so that I can differentiate between the respective tooltip's open and close action?

Please help. Hope I made the problem statement clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two separate state variables

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [open1, open1Set] = useState(false);
  const [open2, open2Set] = useState(false);
};
```

Comment: Is this the best answer for this question ?!
I have the same problem but actualy I have a list of products and I cannot define their the number in advance ! Is there another solution ?

Comment: There's probably a better route when you have `n` number of items, like in a list. Can you create a new question with a sample of your code and link to it here? I'll try to help

Comment: I got the best solution, in case anybody is looking for :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69135132/multiple-material-ui-tooltip-which-open-and-close-separately-onclick-inside-a-li