# Multiple Material-UI Tooltip which open and close separately onClick inside a list

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tooltip

I have a list of products within a react component. Each of them has an information which should be showed separately inside a toolip on click :

https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-galois-tkj73?file=/src/App.js

Is there a way to show them separately and not all at once ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `openTooltip` as an index of the item instead a boolean.

https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-smoke-1itbb?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks alot, But a problem with this solution is when you add a ClickAwayListener around the tooltip :

https://codesandbox.io/s/clickawaylistener-jzuzm?file=/src/App.js

Do you have a suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `openTooltip` as @Viet mentioned, but if you want it to work with `ClickAwayListner` around the tooltip, add:

```
<ClickAwayListener
  mouseEvent="onMouseDown"
  touchEvent="onTouchStart"
  onClickAway={() => {
  ...
  }
>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/clickawaylistener-forked-99m8sk?file=/src/App.js